# Argo Workflow distribution on KOPS cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kops, argo-workflows, argoproj

Using KOPS tool, I deployed a cluster with:

- 1 Master
- 2 slaves
- 1 Load Balancer

Now, I am trying to deploy an Argo Workflow, but I don't know the process. Will it install on Node or Master of the k8s cluster I built? How does it work?

Basically, if anyone can describe the functional flow or steps of deploying ARGO work flow on kubernetes, it would be nice. First, I need to understand where is it deployed on Master or Worker Node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, **kops** creates Kubernetes cluster with [**taints**](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/taint-and-toleration/) on a master node that prevent regular pods scheduling on it.
Although, there was an [issues](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/issues/2856) with some cluster network implementation, and sometimes you are getting a cluster without taints on the master.

You can change taints on the master node by running the following commands:

*add taints (no pods on master):*

```
kubectl taint node kube-master node-role.kubernetes.io/master:NoSchedule
```

*remove taints (allow to schedule pods on master):*

```
kubectl taint nodes --all node-role.kubernetes.io/master-
```

If you want to know whether the taints are applied to the master node of not, run the following command:

```
kubectl get node node-master --export -o yaml
```

Find a `spec:` section. In case the taints are present, you should see something like this:

```
...
spec:
  externalID: node-master
  podCIDR: 192.168.0.0/24
  taints:
  - effect: NoSchedule
    key: node-role.kubernetes.io/master
...
```

Comment: Aaah.. so pods can be created on Master as well and not just Worker nodes unless TAINTS are specified?

Comment: lab@10:~$ kubectl get nodes
NAME       STATUS    ROLES     AGE       VERSION
10.0.1.4   Ready     node      1d        v1.9.5-23+1d79e1112c3ae5-dirty
10.0.1.5   Ready     node      1d        v1.9.5-23+1d79e1112c3ae5-dirty
10.0.1.6   Ready     node      1d        v1.9.5-23+1d79e1112c3ae5-dirty
10.0.1.7   Ready     master    1d        v1.9.5-23+1d79e1112c3ae5-dirty
lab@10:~$ kubectl get node master --export -o yaml
lab@10:~$ kubectl get node master --export -o yaml
Error from server (NotFound): nodes "master" not found

Comment: ^^^ is that how you check? am getting error node not found

Comment: You are using right command. https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#get    Try to run kubectl describe node <master-node-name>

Comment: Check also the "Interacting with Nodes and Cluster" section in the cheatsheet: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/

Comment: kubectl get node 10.0.1.7 --export -o yaml