# Argo workflow controller deployment failing

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, argo-workflows, argo

Argo workflows are stuck in pending state. As specified in another answer on [workflows stuck in pending state](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61802116/7285587), is due to error in workflow controller. Workflow controller is stuck in CrashLoopBackOff because of failure in liveness probe.

[image]

In logs it's showing that controller is failing to access workflow results resource, which might be the reason of it's failure.

[image]

Any idea, how I can fix / debug this situation.

Current:

- Helm chart: argo-workflows
- Chart version: 0.14.0
- Images version: v3.3.2

Upgraded from

- Helm chart: argo
- Chart version: 0.16.10
- Images version: v2.11.6